# How do I print ENTIRE chm document with Windows Help viewer?

Tags: windows, chm

How do I print whole chm document with Windows Help viewer at once? Unfortunately it only allows to print currently selected chapter. I have 38 of them :/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the layout , some of them can be printed by selecting the TOP item Right click, and doing the "print heading and all subtitles" .

The html(s) inside can be busted out of them with 7zip, then the seperate HTMLs can be "macroed"  because you can "step" to the next file with scroll, and therfore repeat actions. GhostMouse or a macro program would set up the "step repeat" actions. Step by hitting the scroll arrow, then select the html to print, then repeat, which can not be done in the normal help reader as easily.

There are 2 conversion methods, to PDF, or to Doc, programs that have trials, but they still are going to be breaking out the htmls, then you select where they go in the other document, then print that document.

There has to be other methods, that was what I could come up with quick